# vim syntax folding (unintentionally) creates nested folds

Tags: regex, vim, folding, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to implement vim folding into an existing syntax file for the fountain.io markup language. The existing syntax file is here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3880

But no matter what I do, my folding region doesn't end where I expect it to. The regexes work perfectly when I test them in search. But when used in a syntax region they created a series of nested folds. The fold starts on the appropriate line, and then the next fold is created inside the existing fold. Essentially I've tried to do the following so that a fold begins on any line that starts with INT or EXT, and ends after a line ends in TO: or a line begins with >:

```
syn region fountainScene start="^\(INT\|EXT\)" end="^\(\(\L\)* TO:\|\s*>\(.*\)\)$" fold transparent contains=fountainCharacter,fountainDialogue,fountainParenthetical,fountainSceneHeading,fountainTransition
```

Even stranger, if I use \ze on my 'end' argument to get the line previous to the matched line, it works as you would expect. It stops the fold on the line above the match, leaving the last line outside the fold. The following will stop folding above a line that says "CUT TO:"

```
\n\ze\(\L\)* TO:\n
```

To troubleshoot, I basically started rebuilding the syntax file from the ground up. Here is what is in the file so far (minus the hi commands) I have extensively modified the regular expressions to prevent them from overlapping with one another. The original regexes had this issue and I thought it might be the cause:

```
syn match fountainCharacter "^\(\s\)*\n\zs\(INT\|EXT\)\@!\(\L\)*[^:]$"
syn region fountainDialogue matchgroup=fountainCharacter start="^\(\s\)*\n\zs\(INT\|EXT\)\@!\(\L\)*[^:]$" end="^\s*$" contains=fountainCharacter,fountainParenthetical
syn match fountainParenthetical "^\s*\((.*)\)$"
syn region fountainSceneHeading start="^\(INT\|EXT\)" end="$" contains=fountainSceneNumber,fountainBoneyard,fountainNotes
syn match fountainTransition "^\(\L\)* TO:$" 
syn region fountainScene start="^\(INT\|EXT\)" end="\n\ze\(\L\)* TO:\n" fold transparent contains=fountainCharacter,fountainDialogue,fountainParenthetical,fountainSceneHeading
```

Thanks for any help you can provide, and please let me know if I've been unclear in any way. I am using MacVim version 7.3.646 custom compiled with python support.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. One of my elements was extending beyond the "end" argument. I had to use the "keepend" argument in my syn region.

This line fixed everything:

```
syn region fountainScene start="^\s*\(\.\|INT\. \|EXT\. \|INT\./EXT\. \|INT/EXT\. \|INT \|EXT \|INT/EXT \|I/E \|int\. \|ext\. \|int\./ext\. \|int/ext\. \|int \|ext \|int/ext \|i/e \)" end="^\(\(\L\)* TO:\|\s*>[^<]*\)$" fold transparent keepend
```

For more details see `:he keepend`